# Proper types for generic onChange handler in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

HTML form implemented with react stateful component. I am trying to write some generic on change handler for form elements but don't succeed to get it typed properly.
Here is the code:

```js
interface SignupState {
    username: string
    email: string
    password: string
    password_confirmation: string
}

class Signup extends React.Component<{}, SignupState> {
    ....
    onFieldUpdate: (k: keyof SignupState) => (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void = (k) => {
        return (e) => {
            this.setState({
                [k]: e.currentTarget.value
            });
        }
    };
}
```

I thought that this way I will be able to put something like `<input onChange={this.onFieldUpdate('username')} />` but have following error on `setState` call:

```
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SignupState | ((prevState: Readonly<SignupState>, props: Readonly<{}>) => SignupState | Pick<SignupState, "username" | "email" | "password" | "password_confirmation"> | null) | Pick<...> | null'.
  Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<SignupState, "username" | "email" | "password" | "password_confirmation">': username, email, password, password_confirmation  TS2345
```